# How to get rid of annoying pop up ads?

Tags: malware, antivirus, ads, popup

When I connect the internet and open any app, a pop-up ad appears randomly.
Ads are still showing, although I did factory reset the phone (all installed apps removed) as well. I also tried to remove the malware app with Avast. Avast detected the issue as well. But couldn't able to remove as well. I uninstalled the malware app which Avast detected. The malware apps installed automatically with another name after uninstalling it. 
How can I get rid of that annoying issue?

Some screenshots of that issue have attached here.
[image: Screenshot one]
[image: Screenshot two]

Comment: Have you tried Addons Detector app to see what is pushing the ads, it is most likely a "free" game? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector

Comment: Use any adblocker app

Comment: Easier solution-factory reset

Comment: @EthanZ I already did that, but the problem not solved :(

Comment: @MdJwelMiah then you need to flash the device with the stock firmware.

Comment: Are you saying that if you factory reset, and do not install **ANY** apps you are still getting these pop-ups? They are 9app pop-ups, they come from installing apps outside of the Play Store, did you try the Addons Detector I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a factory reset didn't fix the issue, the malware responsible for this has embedded itself into the operating system. There is only one solution now. You will have to flash the stock firmware.

Instead of making *another* "how to flash a custom ROM" question, I found an straight forward article that should help you though it.

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281

The ROM you are flashing is provided by the manufacturer of the phone and you should be able to find it on their website.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the effective idea. I did flash my phone as well and all malware get removed :)

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is infected by malwares. If you check your app list, you'll notice that there are unusual apps with sometimes weird names.

To get rid of that, all you have is to uninstall them. There is two methods:

*DISCLAIMER: Do it at your own risk, I won't be held responsible if anything goes wrong.*

1. First the root method: You have to root your phone and then using adb shell, uninstall the apps - a bit tricky and risky as well. You need to install ADB server on your PC (search for Minimal ADB and Fastboot).
   Open it and tape the following:

   `adb shell`

   ```
   `su`

   `mount -o remount, rw /system`

   `cd /system/app`

   `ls (this list all apps on your phone)`
   ```

Then:

```
rm "app_name"
```

*You must tape the exact app name + .apk or .odex*

Do this to all unwanted apps.
You may encounter with apps that can't be removed (operation not permitted), then you need BusyBox installed (Google for that). just let's know, we'll try to help.

2. The second method, less tricky but always risky, is to download [Debloater](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/debloater-remove-carrier-bloat-t2998294), open the USB debugging mode, connect your phone to your computer. You'll see all the installed applications. Just check those you want to remove.

Et voilà.

DON'T REMOVE AN APP IF YOU'RE NOT SURE ABOUT, YOU MAY BRICK YOUR PHONE.

Comment: I've successfully uninstalled some potential malware app by this method those are detected by a malware removal app.

Comment: But one app still couldn't able to uninstall. I think, this the main malware app.

Comment: what do you get as error?

Comment: Do you have BusyBox installed? It provides extra commands to ADB

Comment: No,
Finally, I flash my phone with the stock firmware and all malware apps get removed as well.

Comment: This was the last solution, glad that everything is going fine now

Answer (score -3):

If you have **root** your phone you could use **AdAway** app, that blocks most of the ads